# React and Johnny-Five

Tags: java, reactjs, arduino, johnny-five

I have a nodejs server who controls leds of an Arduino. It runs in http://localhost:3000/led?turn={value}, where my value can be "on" or "off". How can I pass the values from a switch button in my React App?

Answer (score 0):

Simply by parsing the value from `window.location.search`